# Where to store putty generated key file?

Tags: github, putty, tortoisegit

I am trying to get TortoiseGIT to stop nagging me to enter a password every time. I've generated a public key, I've added that key to GitHub and I've generated the keyfile.

1. Where do I store the key file?
2. What other steps am I missing to allow me to not have to enter my password each time?

**UPDATE**

I would still like to know the answer, but ultimately this solved my problem: http://www.munsplace.com/blog/2012/07/27/saving-username-and-password-with-tortoisegit/

Comment: No idea about the steps for tGIT but I imagine they simply consist of providing it with the location of the keyfile. For example, with Putty, mine are stored in `c:\ssh\key` and you specify that location in the session's `connection/ssh/auth` section.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it using [this](http://www.munsplace.com/blog/2012/07/27/saving-username-and-password-with-tortoisegit/). Basically, in Windows 8 you can create a file called _netrc which seems to store general passwords.

Answer (score 1):

You can use PuTTY Pageant authentication agent and load the private key into it. TortoiseGIT should be able to make use of it.